# Using AWS ECS docker containers, can all three required Zookeeper ports be mapped to the host? (Seems not)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-zookeeper, amazon-ecs

Each Zookeeper instance (one per docker container) requires three ports for three distinct purposes (ports 2181, 2888, 3888). It is through these ports that a cluster of these Zookeeper instances (usually 3 to 5 of them) communicate with each other to determine leader, follower (etc).

From my work today (on AWS), it appears that `AWS ECS docker containers` cannot map more than one port to the container host; so I suspect that this cannot be done -- at least not without hassles, which eliminates the simplicity-advantage of using ECS in this scenario.

Is this correct?

Comment: Is it that each container has the single port mapped, for example containerA->2181, containerB->2888, etc?  Or all 3 ports need to be available on each container? Amazon Application load balancer might satisfy the first scenario.

Comment: All three in each and every container.